# Alfresco share customization to create a page within share for alfresco 5.X

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

Alfresco 5.x have been built on top of maven where earlier it was ant.
Can anyone suggest how do i create share page in the alfresco 5.x

Till now we have tried creating page using the below documentation in 
[https://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/tutorial-share-add-page.html](http://Create%20Page)

Let us know how to do the same using alfresco 5.x which gave error using the above documentation.

Comment: How are Maven and Ant relevant for this?

Comment: Earlier versions of alfresco runs on Ant and latest version mentioned above runs on Maven. And we have steps to create a share page in older version, whereas we dont have any documentation that is complient to latest version of Alfresco.

Comment: You can try alfresco sdk to make some customization.